# Android: Trouble with FragmentManager not replacing FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer, fragmentmanager

I'm not able to get my simple fragment to show up upon selecting an option in my navigation drawer the screen just stays blank. The navigation drawer works fine and I know that the `selectItem()` method is firing - the drawer closes after selecting an item because `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);` is called at the end of the `selectItem()` method.

Here is the relevant code from my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {
```

---

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selectItem(position);

    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment = new BookStayFragment();
        args.putString("randomString", "testing this string");

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //This line doesn't seem to be replacing mainContent fragment in activity_main ?
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(myAdapter.customerMainMenu[position]);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);

    }
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

The simple fragment class I'm trying to place into @+id/mainContent

```
package com.example.hotelsystem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BookStayFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView tvTest;

    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "Testing fragment loading from nav drawer";

    public BookStayFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_stay_fragment, container, false);
        tvTest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_stay_text);
        tvTest.setText(getArguments().getString(ITEM_NAME));

        return view;
    }   
}
```

which uses this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/book_stay_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you trying adding a BookStayFragment to the layout in the activity's onCreate, does that work?

Comment: @stkent actually doesn't seem to work no - put the exact same lines in my MainActivity onCreate()

Comment: Can you show the full activity code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bundles` are a collection of **key** / **value** pairs.
A **key** is a string used to identify a **value** so you can then retrieve it again from the `Bundle`.
In your case your **value** is also a string. I believe in this situation you are getting your **keys** and **values** confused.

***Here is what you are currently doing:***

In your `selectItem` method you have:

```
args.putString("randomString", "testing this string");
```

So you are putting a string which contains "testing this string" into args, and assigning it the **key** "randomString".

Then in your `Fragment` class you are setting the text for your `TextView` with:

```
tvTest.setText(getArguments().getString(ITEM_NAME));
```

Here your are getting the arguments bundle that you assigned to the `Fragment` and looking for the string which has the **key** `ITEM_NAME`. You have specified that `ITEM_NAME = "Testing fragment loading from nav drawer"`, but there is no string assigned to the arguments bundle with the **key** "Testing fragment loading from nav drawer". You should instead be looking for the string which has the **key** "randomString".

Comment: shouldn't one or the other string load though? I'm getting no string. Either the ITEM_NAME in my class or the one I've sent as a Bundle with the key randomString.

Comment: actually tried that out and it works fine - pretty silly in hindsight I guess I was over thinking it trying to send a string anyway I can lol. Thanks!

Comment: The `getString` method has two forms. The one you have used is `getString(key)`. The other is `getString(key, defaultValue)`. So in your case if you used `getString("randomString", ITEM_NAME)` it would assign "Testing fragment loading from nav drawer" to your `TextView` if it can't find a string with the **key** "randomString".